# How can I find the upper bound of $E(XYZ)$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expectation

Suppose $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are zero-mean pairwise uncorrelated random variables with variance $\sigma^2$. If we know that $E(XYZ)$ exists and it is a finite number, then how great can it be? I mean, is there any upper bound?

I tried to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and got the following:

$|E(XYZ)|^2 \leq E(X^2) \cdot E(Y^2Z^2) = \sigma^2 E(Y^2Z^2)$

However, how can I find $E(Y^2Z^2)$ ? As far as I understand, if $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated, it doesn't imply that $Y^2$ and $Z^2$ are also uncorrelated.

Any help or hints about possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What has the question about finding an estimate (or estimator) for $E[X Y Z]$ got to do with finding an upper bound on $E[X Y Z]$?

Comment: Yes, perhaps, you're right. I've edited the post.

Comment: You need finite 3rd moments for $E(X_1X_2X_3)$ to be defined (as more than principal value). Otherwise, pick any $R$ with finite 2nd and infinite 3rd moment and let $X_i=B_iR$ where $B_i$ are i.i.d. symmetric Bernoulli on $\{-1,1\}$. Then $E(|X_1X_2X_3|^3)=E(|R|^3)=\infty$. If 3rd moments exist, you can give a non-tight bound as in the deleted answer through Holder's inequality.

Comment: @A.S. can you please give answer with Holder's inequality? I can't figure out :(

Comment: @Evgen $||XYZ||_1\le ||X||_3||Y||_3||Z||_3$. In fact this bound is tight if you consider positive $R$ (with finite 3rd moment) and $X_3=B_1B_2 R$ in my first comment.